# error in importing a .ipynb file in jupyter note book

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

haii i am trying to import  a .ipynb as a module in google colab
so i installed  libarary and tried to import ipynb file but i am getting error

can some body tell me how to resolve this error

```
 !pip install import_ipynb
 import import_ipynb
 import /content/drive/MyDrive/CSRNet-pytorch/make_dataset.ipynb
```

for which i got the error

```
 File "<ipython-input-11-7fb3bfd02505>", line 2
    import /content/drive/MyDrive/CSRNet-pytorch/make_dataset.ipynb
       ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

first move to the dir where the notebook to import is contained with:

```
%cd /path/to/notebook
```

and then:

```
import notebook.ipynb
```